# Trouble formatting symbol-heavy font in MS Word script

Tags: python, fonts, ms-word

I recently wrote a Python program that automates, among other things, the changing of font of text files into Times New Roman Font. The program works pretty well in general, but unfortunately some of the text that I want to convert to Times New Roman font contains large amounts of scientific notation.

Sometimes, these special characters appear as boxes, which would be undesirable. I would also like to avoid a script that is too time-consuming to execute (ie one that cycles through individual characters, identifies the ones with font = "Symbol", and skips formatting of those specific characters), since ideally this script will be used to save time through automation.

The Unicode notation for the text that I am trying to change is the following:

> 25.0 L U+F0BB U+F020 U+F032 U+F035 U+F02E U+F035 U+F030 kg

I've also been looking at ways outside of python to approach the problem (ie looking for macros that can convert text from one notation type to another?), but so far have come up empty.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Would you care to [add some code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

For the font "Symbol", specifically, you might be able to make use of the table at ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/ADOBE/symbol.txt. This is a Symbol-to-Unicode mapping table. Subtract 0xF000 from the Symbol font code value and look up the resulting value in the second column of that chart. The value from the first column is the Unicode. So using your examples above, you'd get:

```
 0xF0BB -> 0xBB -> U+2248 -> '≈'
 0xF020 -> 0x20 -> U+0020 -> ' '
 0xF032 -> 0x32 -> U+0032 -> '2'
 0xF035 -> 0x35 -> U+0035 -> '5'
 0xF02E -> 0x2E -> U+002E -> '.'
 0xF035 -> 0x35 -> U+0035 -> '5'
```

It would be pretty trivial to write some Python code that does a simple lookup of Symbol font code -> Unicode from that chart (a simple dict, really).

**BUT** (there's always a but!) while that might work for your example, there are a few **very important caveats to understand**:

1. Not all of the codes in the chart map to a useful Unicode. Most notably the multi-part parentheses, brackets, and braces, and a few others that map to Private Use Unicodes in that chart.
2. **The chart is only useful for the Symbol font**. There are a number of other fonts (Wingdings, Zapf Dingbats, etc.) which also use this "Symbol-encoding" (codes with U+F0xx), but the glyph shapes in other fonts are different. The chart won't work correctly for those (in many cases, there's no equivalent Unicode).